# code execution slower in half-parallel OpenMP

Tags: c, performance, parallel-processing, openmp, pragma

good day.
I want to implement inner product in 3 method:
1 - sequential
2 - half-parallel
3 - full-parallel

half parallel means multiplication in parallel and summation in sequential.

here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int *x, *y, *z, *w, xy_p, xy_s, xy_ss, i, N=5000;
    double s, e;
    x = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*N);
    y = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*N);
    z = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*N);
    w = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*N);

    for(i=0; i < N; i++) {
        x[i] = rand();
        y[i] = rand();
        z[i] = 0;
    }

    s = omp_get_wtime();

    xy_ss = 0;

    for(i=0; i < N; i++)
    {
        xy_ss += x[i] * y[i];
    }

    e = omp_get_wtime() - s;
    printf ( "[**] Sequential execution time is:\n%15.10f and <A,B> is %d\n", e, xy_ss );


    s = omp_get_wtime();

    xy_s = 0;

    #pragma omp parallel for shared ( N, x, y, z ) private ( i )
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        z[i] = x[i] * y[i];
    }
    for(i=0; i < N; i++)
    {
        xy_s += z[i];
    }

    e = omp_get_wtime() - s;
    printf ( "[**] Half-Parallel execution time is:\n%15.10f and <A,B> is %d\n", e, xy_s );


    s = omp_get_wtime();

    xy_p = 0;

    # pragma omp parallel shared (N, x, y) private(i)
    # pragma omp for reduction ( + : xy_p )
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        xy_p += x[i] * y[i];
    }
    e = omp_get_wtime() - s;
    printf ( "[**] Full-Parallel execution time is:\n%15.10f and <A,B> is %d\n", e, xy_p );
}
```

so I have some question:
first I want to know: does my code correct?!!!!
second: why half-parallel is faster than sequential?!
third: is 5000 a good size for parallelism?
and finally why sequential is the fastest? because of 5000?!
an sample output:

> Sequential execution time is:
>       0.0000196100 and dot is -1081001655
>
> Half-Parallel execution time is:
>      0.0090819710 and dot is -1081001655
>
> Full-Parallel execution time is:
>      0.0080959420 and dot is -1081001655

and for N=5000000

> Sequential execution time is:
>     0.0150297650 and  is -1629514371
>
> Half-Parallel execution time is:
>     0.0292110600 and  is -1629514371
>
> Full-Parallel execution time is:
>     0.0072323760 and  is -1629514371

anyway, why half-parallel is the slowest?

Comment: 5000 multiplications is not worth doing parallel calculations. Cost of thread spawn (or taking thread from pool) and thread join is much higher than actual calculation. You can do an exercise and check yourself what is minimum size of dot product for parallel to be profitable.

Comment: Thank you but I tested for 5000000 and full-parallel is the fastest and half-parallel is the slowest! Why half-parallel is not better than sequential?!

Comment: For loops for seq and parallel are different than half parallel - they do produce different assembly code. Half parallel generates twice the amount of code and you still pay for spawning threads. Increase size of operation to something more realistic like 50 million or so and check again.

Comment: When you split the loops, for your largest case you will have cache evictions and double the number of cache misses in your "half parallel" case. A NUMA platform could exaggerate the problem.   In your smaller case, vectorization with omp simd reduction should be more effective than tthreading.  Depending on your compiler and option settings, you may have achieved this optimization already.  In typical implementations, omp_wtime will not be accurate for such short time intervals.